# Rspec while integrating with Mailchimp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I currently have and app that is using the MailChimp API, whenever someone subscribes it automatically adds them to the Mailchimp list I have set up. The functionality works great but now when I run my test everything that involves creating a subscriber makes my tests fail. The reason is that I don't have a dynamic factory for subscribing people so I get back this failure message `tyler@rowster.com is already subscribed to the list.` It makes sense and mailchimp is doing everything it should but my question is how do I make a dynamic test suite without creating a bunch of fake accounts that pollute my mailchimp list? I know about VCR but is there any other way to handle this? Any help would be great. This is more of looking for advice than a direct question so let me know if you'd like to see any code.

JOB:

```
   class SubscribeUserToMailingListJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(subscriber)
    gb = Gibbon::API.new(ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"])
    gb.lists.subscribe({:id => ENV["MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID"], :email => {:email => subscriber.email}, :merge_vars => {:FNAME => subscriber.first_name, :LNAME => subscriber.last_name}, :double_optin => false})
  end
end
```

INITIALIZER:

```
    Gibbon::API.api_key = ENV["MAILCHIMP_API_KEY"]
Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = true
```

Comment: Just mock your requests to mailchimp, don't bother with VCR

Comment: That sounds fantastic @neo But I'm new to rails and rspec and frankly I have no idea what you mean or how to do it? any idea where I can find some help with that? Sorry newb status...

Comment: Can I see some code?

Comment: Sure, I'm not sure what you want to see but you can see the whole damn project here -> https://github.com/cameronbass/Rowster

Comment: I can also show you individual code I'm just not sure what you need?

Comment: Just the part that you need to mock... Wherever you're making the request to mailchimp?

Comment: updated @neo Is that what you need?

Comment: For gb.lists what's lists? What is the class?

Comment: So basically I have a method in my subscriber model that sends the subscriber after_create to this class. and Gibbon handles the request and just like that I send the `subscriber` to a mailchimp list. To my understanding that is all there is too it. I used this tut to set it up -> http://aspiringwebdev.com/e-mail-in-rails-with-mailchimp-and-mandrill-a-comprehensive-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this in your rspec example:

```
lists = double(:lists)
allow_any_instance_of(Gibbon::API).to receive(:lists) { lists }
allow(lists).to receive(:subscribe) { 'successfully subscribed user.' }
```

You can specify the arguments as well if you want to be specific, it's up to you.

You should give this a good read: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks

Answer (score 1):

neo's answer is good, I've adapted it to current gem version, but it's unreadable as a comment, so I'm posting it as a new answer:

```rb
let(:lists) { double(:lists) }
let(:members) { double(:members) }

before do
  allow_any_instance_of(Gibbon::Request).to receive(:lists) { lists }
  allow(lists).to receive(:members) { members }
  allow(members).to receive(:create) { 'successfully subscribed user.' }
end
```

Comment: I aam getting this error `RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: Gibbon::Request does not implement #lists`